# Docusign Agent have to sign document first before sending it to client

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible through DocuSign so that after completing any application agent will sign the application first before sending it to the client for signature

It means I am expecting a functionality mix of Face to Face and Remote signing.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a special kind of recipient in the DocuSign system called "In Person Recipient" which works exactly how you describe.
The agent gets it and then give his ipad (or whatever device) to the actual signer.

https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-in-person-signing

You can set it using API as well by following this:

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-embedded-signing